# Getting the prior of a specific action like 'Transfer'

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-fusion-apps

I need to fetch the Transfer Out rows of employees which means the prior action or the prior row of the action 'Transfer'. Currently I am doing it it by effective_start_date condition alone. currently this is the code I have put:-

```
SELECT PAAM.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE, PAAM.PERSON_ID,PAAM.ACTION_CODE FROM PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M PAAM 
WHERE
TO_CHAR(PAAM.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') = 
(SELECT TO_CHAR(MAX(PAAM1.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE),'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM FUSION.PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M PAAM1 
WHERE PAAM1.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE< (SELECT MAX(EFFECTIVE_START_DATE) FROM FUSION.PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M PAAM2 WHERE PAAM2.ACTION_CODE='TRANSFER' 
AND PAAM2.PERSON_ID=PAAM1.PERSON_ID AND SYSDATE BETWEEN PAAM2.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PAAM2.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE) AND PAAM1.PERSON_ID=PAAM.PERSON_ID)
```

But by this code I am not getting those employees who have only two rows in their job record- Suppose One is Hire and the other one Transfer. For those employees 'Hire' action would be the Transfer Out row. But both are on the same date. Only effective sequence is different. For these employees I need to add effective sequence logic along with the effective_start_date. I have written the code :-

```
select  PAAM1.effective_start_date, paam1.effective_end_date, paam1.action_code, paam1.effective_sequence  from PER_ALL_assignments_M PAAM,PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M PAAM1, per_all_people_f papf
where PAAM.person_id = paam1.person_id
and paam.person_id=papf.person_id 
and paam.effective_start_date=(select max(paam3.effective_start_date) 
from per_all_assignments_m paam3 where paam.person_id=paam3.person_id) 
and paam.effective_sequence=    
(select max (effective_sequence) from per_all_assignments_m paam4 where paam.person_id=paam4.person_id) 
and paam1.effective_start_date = (SELECT MAX(paam5.EFFective_start_DaTe) from per_all_assignments_m paam5 
where paam5.person_id = paam1.person_id and (paam5.effective_start_date < paam.effective_start_date 
or (paam5.effective_start_date = paam.effective_start_date and paam1.effective_sequence < paam.effective_sequence ))) 
and paam1.effective_sequence =(SELECT MAX(paam6.effective_sequence) from per_all_assignments_m paam6 
where paam6.person_id = paam1.person_id and paam6.effective_start_date = paam1.effective_start_date
and (paam1.effective_start_date<paam.effective_start_date or(paam1.effective_start_date=paam.effective_start_date and paam6.effective_sequence< paam.effective_sequence)))
and paam.action_code='TRANSFER'
```

But this is also not giving me the employees with the same effective dated action as Transfer. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Your queries and explanations are quite hard to understand, it would be good if you edit your question and add examples of your data and expected output. Anyway here is query which works according to specified rules (or at least how I understood them):

```
with 
  data as (
    select effective_start_date esd, effective_end_date eed,
           person_id id, action_code action,
           row_number() over (partition by person_id 
                              order by effective_start_date desc, 
                                       effective_sequence desc) rn
      from per_all_assignments_m p),
  transfers as (
    select id, min(rn) rn from data 
      where action = 'TRANSFER' and sysdate between esd and eed group by id )
select d.id, d.esd, d.action 
  from data d join transfers t on d.id = t.id and d.rn = t.rn + 1
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8f385/1)</sup>

Main part is function `row_number` which enumerates rows separately for each id in proper order, 
next subquery `transfers` finds last 'TRANSFER' for each id and main query (last two lines) assigns prior row to each transfer.